# phpmyadmin login not working suddenly

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know answers for this question is available in various forms. But most of them are new installations or case of change in config / server.

In my case, I am suddenly locked out of phpmyadmin. I am using `root` and was able to login a day before.

No error is shown. It simply redirect to same login page.

1. I checked space on server and its plenty.
2. I am able to login via `ssh`
3. Maximum connection available is 155 of which only ~100-110 are being used.
4. Website using queries on same db with same username password is working just fine.
5. I tried different browsers also.

Edit:  I deleted cached files yesterday. Processor is in good condition. Memory usage also.

Comment: and who is hosting this site

Comment: DigitalOcean. I deleted cached files yesterday. Processor is in good condition. Memory usage also.

Comment: so what does their support team say via chat?

Comment: I tried contacting them for previous issues, but they say they can't do anything inside droplet. Network to droplet looks just ok as website visitors are normal.

Comment: So it is a compute engine or the like that you completely manage versus something they manage.

Comment: yes, i manage it. they don't have access to machine except physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I learned, `df -h` had enough space. But server was full when it comes to `inodes`. To see its status type `df -i`. inode is used to create any file / dir on system. Delete some files and it will start working again.